# Как выложить приложение в play market с низким api?

Tags: android, build, google-play-console, unity3d

Всем привет, я имею аккаун в google developer console и у меня есть игра которая есть на 10 android и выше. Google заявила что с 2020 приложеняи доолжны иметь не меньше 29 api, но как мы уже знаем не у всех телефонах он есть. Я работаю на движке Unity 2020 и компилирую игры с app bundle. В Play Market есть множество игр с 4.4 и выше андроид (standoff 2, brawl srars...). Подскажыте пожалуста, можно ли выложыть игру с низким api, просто меня не пускает и говорит что нужно обновить, или както не через .abb а .apk, ето сработает или чтото нужно изменить? Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Гугл просит указывать в приложении `targetSdkVersion` нужной версии, чтобы добавить её в плей маркет.

А минимальную поддерживаемую `android sdk` вашего приложения, нужно указывать через `minSdkVersion`